# Undefined returned from file existence check

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm checking if a file at a certain local URL exists via a `XMLHttpRequest`, kind of a workaround peek at the filesystem. Using the `pingFile` function described below, I try to see if I get a `200` or `404` for a given file and perform some actions depending on that result.

```
function pingFile(theURL, callback)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
            if (callback !== null) {
                return callback(this.status);
            } else {
                return this.status;
            }
        }
    };
    req.open("HEAD", theURL);
    req.send();
}

var q = pingFile('images/image1.png', null);
```

However, when I check the value of `q`, it is always `undefined`. I'm missing something about the asynchronous nature of an XHR here, I think, but I haven't been able to find where to wait so that `this.status` has either of the values I would expect from a file check.

**EDIT**: I've tried adding `return 4;` after `req.send();` and that always gives `q` the value `4` regardless of whether the file is there.

How do I get the `status` value of a `XMLHttpRequest` back from the function it's in?

Answer (score 0):

For async operations you could use callbacks or promises. Here is a simple example with callbacks:

```
(function () {
    function pingFile(theURL, success, error) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onload = function (e) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                success(e);
            } else {
                error(e);
            }
        };
        req.open("HEAD", theURL);
        req.send();
    }

    function fileExist(e) {
        alert('File exist!');
    }

    function fileNotExist(e) {
        alert('File does not exist!');
    }

    pingFile('images/image1.png', fileExist, fileNotExist);
}());
```

Comment: I'm guessing the brackets can be left off on `fileNotExist()` in the final call to `pingFile`. But I'll try this. Thanks!